# Integral surface of $pq=xy$ through characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The question is using method of characteristics to find the integral surface of 
$pq=xy$ with initial data curve $x=1$, $y=z^2$.

I have tried every possible way but was far away from the result.
The answer i got is
$$x=\cosh t + \frac1s\sinh t ,$$ $$y=2s^3\cosh t +\sinh t ,$$ $$z=\frac{2s^3+s}{2}\cosh 2t+\frac{\sinh 2t+2t}{2} 3s^3-2s^2 t+\frac{s-2s^3}{2} .$$
The problem remains is to eliminate $s$ and $t$ from above equation so we get integral surface and i am helpless

Comment: Are $p, q = \partial_{x} z, \partial_{y} z$?

Comment: @Aka. Are you sure that the condition is $(x=1,y=z^2)$ instead of $(x=1,z=y^2)$ ?

Comment: @JJacquelin yes the condition (x=1,y=z^2) is correct ..

Comment: @Aka. Without context one cannot check if there is a typo or not in the boundary condition. If this is a textbook exercise probably there is something wrong or missing in the wording.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Why did u feel so that something is missing in the wording?

Comment: I wrote "If this is a textbook exercise"  because without context.

Comment: @JJacqueline It was given in classroom for assingnment

Comment: Now that I know for sure that this is an academic exercise, I am quite certain that there is something wrong or missing in the wording of the problem. Sorry, finding what is wrong or missing is not for me. I can only guess that the boundary condition was not correctly transcribed but the mistake can be else.

Comment: @JJacqueline the question is correct...

Comment: Your answer is not right. According to it, $y(0)=2s^3$ and $z(0)=s$, hence the initial condition $y=z^2$ is not satisfied.